# How to seperate radiobuttons from radiobuttonlist and set it default

Tags: yii, yii-events

I'm new to Yii framework. I'm using two radiobuttonlist in my advanced search form. I'm using the below lines to create radiobuttonlist.

```
<div class="row">
        <?php #echo $form->label($model,'ReviewedDate'); ?>     
                <?php echo $form->radioButtonList($model, 'ReviewedDate', 
        array('1' => 'Reviewed', '' => 'Not Reviewed')
    ); ?>
    </div>

       <div class="row"> 
                <?php echo $form->radioButtonList($model, 'Approved', 
        array('0' => 'Rejected', '1' => 'Approved')
    ); ?> 
    </div>
```

Now, I want to create a seperate radiobutton(4 buttons - Approved, Rejected, Reviewed, Not Reviewed) from the radiobuttonlist and `Not reviewed` has to be the selected by default when I go to that page.At a time only one button can be selected. How can I do this

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
        <div class="row">
            <?php #echo $form->label($model,'ReviewedDate'); ?>     
                    <?php echo $form->radioButtonList($model, 'ReviewedDate', 
            array('1' => 'Reviewed', '' => 'Not Reviewed','2'=>'Approved','3'=>'Reviewed','4'=>'rejected'
        ); ?>
        </div>
<script> $( document ).ready(function() {
      $('your id /selector radio button').prop('checked',true);
    }); </script>
```